# Recreate deleted orders?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

The client has unfortunately deleted some orders from the Craft Commerce plugin. Does anyone know if it's possible to recreate deleted orders?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to find a database backup that has the order information that was deleted and write a script that re-inserts that order info into your existing database.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've now tried to recreate the orders, but it seems that there's a lot of dependencies and several tables that need an insert from backup database. Does anyone have such a script?